# Spring register bean in runtime

Tags: java, spring

I would like to register spring bean in runtime, so i built that class:

```
public class SpringBeanRegister implements BeanRegister, ApplicationContextAware {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    public void registerBean(Object object) {
        ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory = context.getBeanFactory();
        factory.registerSingleton("beanName", object);
    }

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.context = (ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext; // -- safe?
    } 

}
```

is this cast always safe ?

Comment: Next time chose a better title, that matches the question a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment (Spring 4.1) there is only implementation of `ApplicationContext` that does not implement the `ConfigurableApplicationContext` interface: that is `org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StubWebApplicationContext` from `spring-test`

So I think you are relative save and need to pay some attention to the tests.

**But just because there is no meaningful implementation at the moment, it does not mean that there is no change in future version, or somebody/some Framework has implemented it already!**